# Definition of a cut

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

This is going to be obvious but the correction of an exercise made me doubt about the definition of the capacity of a cut in a flow:

[image: Exercise]

I though that the capacity of a cut was the sum over the ingoing and outgoing edges of the capacity, where we multiply the capacity of ingoing edges by $-1$ and outgoing by $1$. So this would produce $1\cdot 2-1\cdot1+1\cdot 2$ for this cut=3.

I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The capacity of the cut is the *maximum possible total flow* from red vertices to black vertices, ignoring what happens internally in each part.

Even tough it is *allowed* to send 1 unit of flow along the back edge, doing so is not *required*. And doing it would just reduce the total net flow, so when we're *maximizing* that flow we'll assume that the back edge is *not* utilized.

Thus that capacity of the cut is just the sum of the *forward* edges across the cut, ignoring backwards ones.